# Bad Username in /etc/crontab

Tags: cron, raspberrypi, debian

I don't get it. The log told me, that the username is bad, but it don't seems to be.

**From /var/log/syslog**

```
Nov  9 09:10:42 INT-PI-PREPARE01 systemd[1]: cron.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Nov  9 09:10:42 INT-PI-PREPARE01 systemd[1]: cron.service: Succeeded.
Nov  9 09:10:42 INT-PI-PREPARE01 cron[906]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Nov  9 09:10:42 INT-PI-PREPARE01 cron[906]: Error: bad username; while reading /etc/crontab
Nov  9 09:10:42 INT-PI-PREPARE01 cron[906]: (*system*) ERROR (Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)
Nov  9 09:10:42 INT-PI-PREPARE01 cron[906]: (CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)
```

**My /etc/crontab file**

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )

# > --- Manually Crontabs ---
0 */12  * * *   root    shutdown -r now > /dev/null 2>&1
*/10    * * * * root    python3 /opt/scripts/measuretempalert.py > /dev/null 2>&1
```

FYI: The Python script works well. Any Ideas? The **crontab -e** is empty untill the last line.

Comment: Maybe you have some weird non-printing characters there? What does `cat -vT /etc/crontab` output?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think so: https://pastebin.com/raw/vejzwWV1

Comment: Please use `sudo crontab -e` to add your custom crontab entries in a safe way instead of editing /etc/crontab. You may perhaps resolve the issue by purging `cron` and reinstalling it.

Comment: Based on your pastebin output, your whole /etc/crontab file appears to have DOS-style line endings (the `^M` indicates a CR)

Comment: Based on the comment from @steeldriver I've generate a new /etc/crontab file and it seems to be working right now. I will wait till tomorrow but it looks good.